# Spring integration priority channel with round robin consumer

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a kind of Priority Channel with spring integration but I am blocked and didn't find a solution on the web.

I would like to read multiples channel (6) alternatively with a service activator. Each channel is for a priority level (CRITICAL, HIGHEST, HIGH, NORMAL, LOW, LOWEST). Message come from RabbitMQ and are distributed on correct channel with a Router.

The problem is that I would like to create a Service Activator who read alternatively in the channels using a round robin based on time.

For example, CRITICAL should have a 5 secondes running time, and then the service switch to HIGHEST for 3 seconds, and then to HIGH for 1 second, ...

Is it possible to do it properly with spring integration ?
Maybe I don't use the correct component to do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Priority Channel pattern works a bit different way.
It is a queue with sort support. When a new message arrives to the queue it is sorted to the proper place according to its `priority`. That absolutely does matter how your consumer of this channel works. The priority happens only in the channel. The consumer just polls messages from that queue like they are ordered for it: the CRITICAL, than HIGHEST, if CRITICAL aren't present and so on.

On the other hand, if you distribute messages by priority do different channels, why just don't have separate Service Activators for each of those channels? And each priority will be read by its own process.

There is no such a solution based on the "time to run". It just doesn't seem with a good fit for messaging architecture. Although you might can implement via scheduled task `cancel()` or Quartz to "perform task until...".

**UPDATE**

Regarding time control, I think you can come up with the solution which in the infinite loop really `start()`s different service activators and `stop()`s them after an appropriate scheduled time. All those service activators should listen to different queue channels.

Comment: I thought about having one service activator by channel but the problem is that i need to be sure that critical message are processed before lower level, but not ALL, just a maximum possible in the specified time (and you can imagine the higher is the level, the higher is the time allowed). The idea is to avoid a channel to block the other to many time. Now, I'm trying to find if it is possible to have a service activator controller who can juste start and stopans restart different service activators on demand.

Comment: Please, fine some update in my answer. Not sure if we can somehow wrap it to some generic solution to place as an out-of-the-box feature to the Framework... But of course, any further ideas are welcome!